# weighted mean square error

Tags: model, mse

Here is something from my text:

"A model's fit to new data can be summarized numerically by mean square error , $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}[y_i-E(y_i|\theta)]^2$, or weighted version such as $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}[y_i-E(y_i|\theta)]^2/var(y_i|\theta)$"

I was considering the general regression problem, so $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\epsilon_i$, in this case $y_i \sim N(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i,1)$ if $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,1)$. So in this case does that mean $var(y_i|\theta)=1$?

But my question is, if we have another model, like say the model is not normal, and might be not a regression question. So in general, does that also mean we need to find the distribution of $y_i|\theta$ first, then find out what is $var(y_i|\theta)$?

Thanks!